# Delete Text by Fading It

Tags: overlays, deletion

I once saw a feature in Vim where, when I delete the text to the left of the cursor, the text is indeed deleted. However, a faint impression of the text remains in its original place, as shown in the figure below.

The original text was

```bash
alias ll='ls -l'■
```

After deleting to the left, it becomes

[image]

The right side of the cursor shows the text that originally existed there to remind me what I just deleted. They won't be retained in the final saved file.

---

The advantages of this are self-evident. I want to ask if there's a package in Emacs that can implement a similar feature.

Comment: What is the name of this Vim feature ?

Comment: @TristanRiehs: Sorry, I'm not a Vim expert, I didn't think to proactively check out a feature's name, and I don't know how to do that. I experienced this feature on a Vim with an existing configuration, and I haven't touched that Vim since. But I'll update this question if I find useful information.